# function in component not executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react functional component for a timesheet app where users select times and the app tells them the total time they worked that week. In my component I have a function which takes a series of values and adds them up together to get a weekly total of hours worked.

I'm getting a strange result where if I organize the code one way, it works, but

this works:

```
  const calculateFinalTime = (times) => {
    const totalMinutes = times.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      return typeof cur.resultM === "number" ? (acc += cur.resultM) : acc;
    }, 0);
    const finalHrs = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60);
    const finalMins = totalMinutes % 60;
    const stringHrs = String("0" + finalHrs).slice(-2);
    const stringMins = String("0" + finalMins).slice(-2);
    const finalTime = `${stringHrs}:${stringMins}`;
    return finalTime;
  };
  console.log(calculateFinalTime(times));
```

By works I mean I get a value for the sum in the console

But this doesn't:

```
  const [finalTime, setFinalTime] = useState("");

  const calculateFinalTime = (times) => {
    const totalMinutes = times.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      return typeof cur.resultM === "number" ? (acc += cur.resultM) : acc;
    }, 0);
    const finalHrs = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60);
    const finalMins = totalMinutes % 60;
    const stringHrs = String("0" + finalHrs).slice(-2);
    const stringMins = String("0" + finalMins).slice(-2);
    const finalTime = `${stringHrs}:${stringMins}`;
    setFinalTime(finalTime);
  };

  console.log(finalTime);
```

For some reason, no value is showing up in my console. Nor does it work if I try to display the value in a div.

Anybody can clue me in on why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that the second code snippet doesn't call `calculateFinalTime`, it just tries to use `finalTime`.

Comment: Yup. This was it. The other answer may have played a role too (not sure), but the problem was I thought the function would automatically be executed when the component renders

Answer (score 2):

I guess that's because of using duplicated variable's name for "finalTime".

think if you change just one variable name, it will work well.

```
const calculateFinalTime = (times) => {
    const totalMinutes = times.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      return typeof cur.resultM === "number" ? (acc += cur.resultM) : acc;
    }, 0);
    const finalHrs = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60);
    const finalMins = totalMinutes % 60;
    const stringHrs = String("0" + finalHrs).slice(-2);
    const stringMins = String("0" + finalMins).slice(-2);
    const finalTime1 = `${stringHrs}:${stringMins}`;
    setFinalTime(finalTime1);
  };

  console.log(finalTime);
```

Comment: This may have played a role, I think the other issue was I wasn't actually calling the function like the other answer suggested. Thanks for your help Youngsoo

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have multiple variables with the same name, the scoped variable should take precedence. otherwise you would have at least a syntax error in the console of already declared variable. Either way the code below is a replicate of your code and it works just fine.

```js
function MyComponentClass () {
  const { useState, useEffect } = React

  const [testTime, setTestTime] = useState(0);
  const [finalTime, setFinalTime] = useState('');
  
  const calculateFinalTime = (times) => {
    const totalMinutes = times.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      return typeof cur.resultM === "number" ? (acc += cur.resultM) : acc;
    }, 0);
    const finalHrs = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60);
    const finalMins = totalMinutes % 60;
    const stringHrs = String("0" + finalHrs).slice(-2);
    const stringMins = String("0" + finalMins).slice(-2);
    const finalTime = `${stringHrs}:${stringMins}`;
    setFinalTime(finalTime);
  };
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    calculateFinalTime([{resultM: Number(testTime)}]);
  }, [testTime]);
  
  
  return <div>
  <input type="number" step="1" value={testTime} onChange={(event) => setTestTime(event.target.value)} />
  <h1>Hello world {finalTime} </h1>
  </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponentClass />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```